# inserting multiple record using foreach loop c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, loops, foreach

I am creating a web app in which i need to insert multiple records in my database, this is how it is looking

```
List<string> td = tdate.Split(',').ToList();
//List<string> ps = particular.Split(',').ToList();
int i = 0;
foreach (string t in td)
foreach (string p in ps)
     {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into finalinstructoreexpense(sonvinid,particulars,amount,totalamt,date,utno,paymentid,paymode,issuedate,sondate,trainer,type,bank_id) values(@sonvinid,@particulars,@amount,@totalamt,@date,@utno,@paymentid,@paymode,@issuedate,@sondate,@trainer,@type,@bank_id)", con);
       con.Open();
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@sonvinid", SqlDbType.Int).Value =Convert.ToInt32(id);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@particulars", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = p;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@amount",SqlDbType.Float).Value=adjamt.Split(',')[i];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@totalamt", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = total;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date.Split(',')[i];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@utno", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = utrno;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@paymentid",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value=paymentid;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@paymode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = modeofpayment;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@issuedate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = transferdate;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@sondate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = t;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@trainer", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = trainer;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = typeofadj;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@bank_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(bnkid);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       message = "Adjusted Amount Inserted Successfully";
       con.Close();
     }
```

this problem is i have 4 arrays in the form of string `i.e tdate,particular,adjamt,date` and the parameters look like

```
tdate(01-01-2013,03-01-2013)
particular(105,100)
adjamt(500,650)
date(2015,2016)
```

and this is how i want to enter the records in the database

```
(01-01-2013,105,500,2015)
(03-01-2013,100,650,2016)
```

but this is how it is actually inserting in my databas

```
(01-01-2013,105,500,2015)
(03-01-2013,105,500,2015)
```

it means only tdate is working properly but the values of other parameters are not changing and inserting the first value only, what i need to do, if i want to enter the records propely

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initialising `i` to zero:

```
int i = 0;
```

but not incrementing it in your loop. So these lines:

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@amount",SqlDbType.Float).Value=adjamt.Split(',')[i];
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date.Split(',')[i];
```

are always returning the first element of the array.

Add:

```
i = i++;
```

to the end of your loop.

You really should split `adjamt` and `date` into lists before looping and use those lists inside the loop.

You are also looping over both `td` and `ps`. This will add twice as many rows into your table as you want. Remove the inner loop and replace:

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@particulars", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = p;
```

by

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@particulars", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ps[i];
```

where `ps` is created outside your loop:

```
var ps = particular.Split(',').ToList();
```